# symfony twig batch reference to array error

Tags: symfony, twig, rendering

I use the following twig to generate items per row

```
{% for row in products|batch(3, 'No item') %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for product in row %}
            <div class="col-lg-{{}}"></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

inside of row loop where I output details about product I have referencies to functions where I pass the product array like

```
<a href="{{ productUrl(product) }}"></a>
```

but this code does not work if I use batch I get the following error

```
getProductUrl() must be of the type array, string given
```

Comment: Where have you defined your funtion `productUrl()` ?

Answer (score 1):

1 - You can't use a function in twig unless you define it in a custom twig extension [Doc Here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

2 - If the url is one from your route, you should use `path` function from Twig.

3 - Else, If your custom method (`productUrl`) is defined in `Product` entity, Make sure variable `product` inside the loop is an instance of `Product` class. You can access to the method as `product.productUrl`.

Let us know if you need something else.

Comment: 1 - You can also defined a macro in twig :)

Comment: Macro will help you not to write in twig repeatedly, But if the output is dependent from container or entity like in this case, and its not beyond usage of `path` an `extension` can be useful as it can re-use existing services as well as `Twig Environment`

Comment: Yes I agree with that !